# Php, is it a bad sign if a method is only allowed to be called from another method?

Tags: php

its a gaming site, and we store scores:

```
class Game
{
    public function addScore($player, $score)
    {
        INSERT INTO game .........
    }
}
```

administrators may erase scores so lets add a removal method too:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    DELETE FROM game .........
}
```

now the problem is, deletion is logged, so we must wrap this code:

Controller:

```
$log->addLog('user deletetion');
$game->delete($id);
```

So when we delete this game in controller, the logging takes place too. Now here comes the problem: in code, nothing prevents to just call the `$game->delete();` method! This is bad, because if any rookie start using this code, he cant know that deletion must come with logging. Is this a sign of something, or??

Comment: So put logging in the Delete method

Comment: put in user roles and test user access before deleting

Comment: no, then "Game" class would do "too much" (SRP)

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to write the log before deletion it's completely fine to just add the logging into the delete() method as RiggsFolly suggested as this is an "atomic" operation.

You would violate SRP if for example apart from logging+deletion you would pop up a dialog in the very same method. As you would mix data handling and UI in the same method. This is two separate responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using a Facade pattern. You need something like this

```
class GameFacade{
    public function __constructor(Game $game, Logger $logger){
       $this-game = $game;
       $this-logger = $logger;
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        $this->game->delete($id);
        $this->logger->log("Game deleted");
    }
}
```

So, now we have to use only this facade to work with `Game` entity. Obviously, you can't prevent new comers from using `Game` delete method directly, but at least you can make some kind of convention to use only entity facade.
Another way that you can chose is to use a fabric pattern to generate entities. Please, read more about patterns, but you also should use them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#PHP) to decorate your `Game` class with logging. That way you log every time someone calls the delete method and keep it outside of the `Game` class.

Here is a guide on how to do it in Symfony framework to give you an idea: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html